# Iteration of generic Functions

Tags: java, function, generics

I want to create a List of Functions, that has following behaviour:

```
     static List createList(){
         Function<A,B> f1;
         Function<B,C> f2;
         Function<C,D> f3;
         Function<D,A> f4;
         return Arrays.asList(f1,f2,f3,f4);
     }
```

It's just an example. I would like to have a list, that could have any size and where the parameter of the next function is the result of the function before.
Is there any way how I parametrize the return type? List of what?

I want to give this list to a method, that enforces to get a list of the above described behaviour. Example:

```
    public void process(List/** generic type? **/ list){
        Object res = null;
        for(Function f : list){
            // do work
            System.out.print("works result");
            res = f.apply(res);
            // do other work
        }
    }
```

Although I would like "res" to be generic. As same as List. And the Functions as well. I would **not** like to use "Function< ?, ?>". 
Do you have some idea, how to do that?

Comment: By "function" you mean invocable java methods?

Comment: `List<Function<?,?>>`

Comment: Looks like you want to have a function composition which is simple in Java 8, but why do you enforce the input of the `process` method to be a list of Functions rather than just a Function (which, in specific case, could be internally composed of multiple functions)?

Comment: No, there is no way to enforce that constraint to an arbitrary size list thru  generic typing. List<Function> is the best you can do. However I think you may want to consider Java 1.8 Streams, like Danio says. It will depend on what you want to accomplish here. Perhaps you should give us the actual use case.

Comment: Sounds good, but how does a function composition look like? Currently I have no idea.

The reason for the list was that each function should be called separately from the other functions.

Comment: So you need to execute an arbitrary line of code between each function like the "works result" print-out in you revised example? I may post a solution based on streams that would execute the functions in order but you cannot inject your code between steps; the stream would need to have such a code already added.

Comment: I really have no idea how a solution with streams can look like. Can you post an example?

Answer (score 2):

Forget about using a `List`, you don't need that.

In Java you can directly combine functions and only return the "overall" function, avoiding the client code to iterate manually on a list of functions (reduces the errors by enforcing the order, makes the code simpler).

```
private static <A, B, C> Function<A, A> createFunction() {
    Function<A, B> f1 = //TODO
    Function<B, C> f2 = //TODO
    Function<C, A> f3 = //TODO

    return f1.andThen(f2).andThen(f3);
}
```

Comment: But with this solution I will not be able to call f1 in the first run and later f2 in a second run (for example, if f2 should be called if an event occured, not earlier).

Comment: @henry86 Indeed you must either call the whole resulting function or nothing with this approach. If your use case is to call some functions in case of some events, could you update your question to reflect this problematic please ?

Comment: @henry86 As Valentin Ruano explained in the comments, depending on your real use case, a `Stream` could even be the *thing* to use...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you.

```
public class A : ITest
{

}

public class B : ITest
{

}

public class C : ITest
{

}

public class D : ITest
{

}

static List createList(){
         Function<ITest,ITest> f1 = new Function<A,B>;
         Function<B,C> f2 = new Function<B,C>;
         Function<C,D> f3 = new Function<C,D>;
         Function<D,A> f4 = new Function<D,A>;
         return Arrays.asList(f1,f2,f3,f4);
     }

public void process(ArrayList<Function<ITest,ITest>> list){
        //do some stuff
    }
```

where ITest is an interface that you should define for those classes.

Answer (score -1):

Time for run-time type information, though this is almost a *typeless* usage.
Hence query yourself whether the class needs generic paramters or whether it suffices to have `Class<?> domainType` and `rangeType` (that is a constructor with )`.

```
public static class TypedFunction<D,R> {
    public final Class<D> domainType;
    public final Class<R> rangeType;
    public final Function<D, R> function;
    public TypedFuntion(Class<D> domainType, Class<R> rangeType, Function<D, R> function) {
        this.domainType = domainType;
        this.rangeType = rangeType;
        this.function = function;
    }
}

 static List<TypedFunction<?,?>> createList(){
     Function<A,B> f1;
     Function<B,C> f2;
     Function<C,D> f3;
     Function<D,A> f4;
     return Arrays.asList(
          new TypedFunction(A.class, B.class, f1),
          new TypedFunction(B.class, C.class, f2),
          ...);
 }
```

This allows the functions to be used, however cumbersome.

```
TypedFunction f = ...
Object a = ...
B b; // Non-generic class B
if (B.class.isAssignableFrom(f.rangeType)) {
    b = (B) f.apply(f.domainType.cast(a));
}
```